# Promises, rejections, and errors - Trying to found a solution for highly cadenced async operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

First, I apologize for a rudimentary question but I have spent days reading on Async functions and have yet to find a solution or gain understanding. I promise if I get help I'll pay it forward later here.

I have a set of operations, or tasks, that I am supposed to execute one at a time. Task one is to run, then task two, then task three.

The problem is this:

For all tasks execute a random number, x, of write operations to a folder. Each task is to be done until completion and then move to the next task.

Task 1: 
Log to the console when you start to write the file Task1_1. When the file is done writing, log 'Finished writing Task1_1'. Move to Task1_1+1 until reach Task1_X.

Task 2: 
Write all tasks at the same "time". Finish writing all files before you move to the next task.

Task 3: 
30% of the Files are to be written to a bad path. If it is written to a bad path, write "Failed to write File Task3_X" otherwise follow the same pattern as task 1.

I have tried to use Async and await, I have tried traditional callbacks. I am most comfortable with promises but I am clearly missing a key conceptual understanding of what is happening (if this bothers you... I am sorry.. people have been kind harsh about my level on here.. just trying to learn).

```
function writeFileAsync(directory, file){
    return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
        console.log(`Writing File ${file}`)
        fs.writeFile(path.join(directory,file), 'this is a file', (err) => {
            if(err){
                reject(err)
            } else{
                resolve()
            }
        })
    })
}

function taskOne(x, location){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log('** Starting task taskOne **')
        let i = 1;
        while(i <= x){
            let name = `taskOne_${i}`;
            writeFileAsync(location,name)
            .then(logCompletion(name))
            .then(i++)
        }
        console.log('** Finished with taskOne **')
    })
}

function taskTwo(x, location){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log('** Starting task taskTwo **')
        let i = 1;
        while(i <= x){
            let name = `taskTwo_${i}`;
                writeFileAsync(location, name)
                .then((success) => logCompletion(name))
                .then(i++)
        }
        console.log(`** Finished with taskTwo **`)
    })
}

function taskThree(x, location){
    return new Promise( resolve => {
        console.log('** Starting task taskThree **')
        const badPath = path.join(__dirname,`/notHome`);
        const randomlyDelayedIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(x+1)+1);
        const isItGoodOrBad = () => { 
            let chance =  Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(10)+1) 
            return chance < 7 ? true : false
        }
        let i = 1;
        while(i <= x){
            let name = `taskThree_${i}`;
            let directionIsGood = isItGoodOrBad();
            if(directionIsGood){
                debugger
                writeFileAsync(location, name)
                .then(logCompletion(name))
                .then(i++)
            } else{
                writeFileAsync(badPath, name)
                .then((success)=> logCompletion(name))
                .catch((err) => console.log(`Failed to write ${name}`))
                .then(i++)
            }
        }
        console.log(`** Finished with taskThree **`)
    })
}

function main(){
    const folderName = String(Date.now());
    const x = Number(folderName.slice(-1));
    const location = path.join(__dirname,folderName);
    fs.mkdir(location, ()=> {});
    return taskOne(7, location)
    .then(taskTwo(7,location))
    .then(taskThree(7,location)) 
}


main();
```

I expect (might change cadence depending on randomness):

```
Starting Task1
Writing Task1_1
Finished Task1_1
Writing Task1_2
Finished Task1_2
etc.... 
Finished with Task1

Starting Task2
Writing Task2_1
Writing Task2_2
Writing Task2_2
etc...
Finished Task2_1
Finished Task2_2
Finished Task2_3
etc...
Finished with Task2

Starting Task3
Writing Task3_1
Failed to Write Task3_1
Writing Task3_2
Finished Writing Task3_2
Writing Task3_3
Finished Writing Task3_3
Finished Task3
```

What I am getting is something like this:

```
** Starting task taskOne **
Writing File taskOne_1
Finished Writing file taskOne_1
Writing File taskOne_2
Finished Writing file taskOne_2
Writing File taskOne_3
Finished Writing file taskOne_3
Writing File taskOne_4
Finished Writing file taskOne_4
Writing File taskOne_5
Finished Writing file taskOne_5
Writing File taskOne_6
Finished Writing file taskOne_6
Writing File taskOne_7
Finished Writing file taskOne_7
** Finished with taskOne **
** Starting task taskTwo **
Writing File taskTwo_1
Writing File taskTwo_2
Writing File taskTwo_3
Writing File taskTwo_4
Writing File taskTwo_5
Writing File taskTwo_6
Writing File taskTwo_7
** Finished with taskTwo **
** Starting task taskThree **
Writing File taskThree_1
Finished Writing file taskThree_1
Writing File taskThree_2
Writing File taskThree_3
Writing File taskThree_4
Finished Writing file taskThree_4
Writing File taskThree_5
Finished Writing file taskThree_5
Writing File taskThree_6
Writing File taskThree_7
Finished Writing file taskThree_7
** Finished with taskThree **
Failed to write taskThree_2
Failed to write taskThree_3
Failed to write taskThree_6
Finished Writing file taskTwo_1
Finished Writing file taskTwo_2
Finished Writing file taskTwo_3
Finished Writing file taskTwo_6
Finished Writing file taskTwo_7
Finished Writing file taskTwo_4
```

Comment: `writeFileAsync` returns a Promise, but you're never consuming those Promises anywhere

Comment: You need to map your file operations into a series of Promises and then use Promise.all

Comment: Off-topic note: Ignorance is welcome on Stack Overflow. Conceptual understanding is why people come here in the first place. What we get annoyed about is when people expect us to solve their entire tasks for them, while they show no effort of their own (typically by copy-pasting their assignments). It is also somewhat irksome (but to a much lesser degree) when people post questions with insufficient detail. SO is a great place, but we do expect you to act as if there's real people doing this for their own education and relaxation on the other end, not slaves to do your bidding. You'll do fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing synchrouous and async code. You can rewrite, for example, your `taskOne` as the following:

```
const writeFileAsync = () => {
   return Promise.resolve();
};

const logCompletion = (n) => {
   console.log(n);
   return Promise.resolve();
};

async function taskOne(x, location){
        console.log('** Starting task taskOne **')
        let i = 1;
        while(i <= x){
            let name = `taskOne_${i}`;
            await writeFileAsync(location,name)
            .then(logCompletion(name))
            .then(i++)
        }
        console.log('** Finished! with taskOne **')
}

async function taskTwo(x, location){
        console.log('** Starting task taskTwo **')
        let i = 1;
        while(i <= x){
            let name = `taskTwo_${i}`;
            await writeFileAsync(location,name)
            .then(logCompletion(name))
            .then(i++)
        }
        console.log('** Finished with taskTwo **')
}

taskOne(12).then(() => taskTwo(12));
```

You can check out an example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KLBwby

You should be able to figure out the rest, I think.

Comment: Thank you Vaughan! So when I write the function to write the file it would be: 

writeFileAsync = (location, name) => {
   return new Promise( resolve, reject => {
       fs.WriteFile(path.join(location,name), 'content', ()=> {})
       resolve();
       reject(err);
    })
}

?

Comment: Your current `writeFileAsync` function is fine. I merely gutted it here since Codepen doesn't run on Node (it runs in the browser) and I wanted to demonstrate something working on the web. If you just use yours, it should work the fine. The trick is in how you use _async_ and _await_. `await` signals to the calling code to suspend execution of the functions until the async operation is finished...

Comment: Cool, you can report back if you have troubles.

Comment: Ohhhhh my looordddd thank you!!! I am going to work through task three now. Seriously.. I know someone out there has asked this question but I have searched up and down. I promise your answer will help a lot of people. thank you so much. For real!

Comment: Cool, glad you got it. FYI this is covered here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises However, I can understand that while you're just learning it, it can be hard to figure out the applications. Best of luck!

Comment: I have a question-  I think its at the root of one of my misunderstandings- I have the below code: 

async function taskTwo(x, location){
        ..... (helper function that returns a promise)

        await runTheFile()
        console.log(`** Finished with taskTwo **`)
}

why don't I get that console log? I have also tried it with a .then(console.log) and a .then( () => console.log)

Comment: We're probably better off taking this to chat, since it's out of scope of the question.